# What are the differences between Theta* and Field D*?

Tags: ds.algorithms, shortest-path

Both Theta* and Field D* are variations on the A* algorithm, but are adapted for any-angle pathfinding rather than pathfinding constrained to a grid. The primary difference between these two algorithms that I've seen is that Field D* can quickly recalculate the path at any time to adjust if the grid changes, while Theta* provides no such functionality.

Besides this change, what are the major differences between these algorithms? What are the pros/cons? Which is faster, and which will generate a superior path?

Comment: The authors of Theta\* have an alteration of Theta\* called Phi\* that *can* quickly recalculate the path after grid-changes.  I haven't read the paper for Field D*, so I'm not sure what the difference between the two is yet.  I've been meaning to do that anyways; I'll try to at least skim it in the next few days for you.

Comment: Please provide references for the Theta* and Field D* algorithms.  The question suggests that you think A* is limited to path-finding in a grid, which is simply not true; A* is a heuristic for quickly finding shortest paths in _arbitrary_ graphs.